# Publish npm package on guest computer

Tags: npm, package

I had published an `npm` package on my personal pc.

Say, i am away from my personal PC and i wish to update the `npm` package from a guest computer.

Do i need to `adduser` to guest computer from command line?
Is there any browser based way to update the package?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can simply `adduser` on the new computer and enter the correct credentials.

Comment: actually i am looking for browser based technique